# What does in/out actually do in Kotlin when passed as arguments?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want to understand `in` and `out` in Kotlin. As I found theory is, consumer `in` takes and producer `out` returns.

But how does two methods below differentiate when `in` and `out` are taken as method arguments where we can access `list` without any issue?

```
private fun exampleMethod1(list: ArrayList<out String>) {}

private fun exampleMethod2(list: ArrayList<in String>) {}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let me demonstrate what `in`/`out` do with the help of an example. Consider the following:

```
private fun foo(list: ArrayList<Number>) {}

private fun bar(list: ArrayList<Number>) {}
```

Now we try to pass an `ArrayList` to each function, each with a different generic type parameter:

```
// Error: Type Mismatch. Required `ArrayList<Number>` Found `ArrayList<Int>`
foo(arrayListOf<Int>())

// Error: Type Mismatch. Required `ArrayList<Number>` Found `ArrayList<Any>`
bar(arrayListOf<Any>())
```

But we get errors! How do we solve that? We have to tell the compiler somehow that, for `foo` the list can also contain elements of a subtype of `Number` (e.g. `Int`) and for `bar` we have to tell the compiler that the list can also contain elements of a basetype of `Number` (e.g. `Any`).

```
private fun foo(list: ArrayList<out Number>) {}

private fun bar(list: ArrayList<in Number>) {}
```

And now it works!

[Further reading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

Comment: So out is basically extend down, while in is extend up? *up being the more generic class (e.g: Number implements Any)

Comment: if only the official docs explained it as simply.

Comment: Can't build when I change ArrayList to List! Why?

Answer (score 20):

### Type Projection

When the modifier `in` or `out` is used in the function parameter, it's called *type projection*.

| Projections | Produces | Consumes | Function Behaviour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `ArrayList<out Orange>` | `Orange` | `Nothing` | Accepts subtypes of `ArrayList<Orange>` |
| `ArrayList<in Orange>` | `Any?` | `Orange` | Accepts supertypes of `ArrayList<Orange>` |
| `ArrayList<Orange>` | `Orange` | `Orange` | Doesn't accept any subtypes or supertypes |

`ArrayList` in Kotlin is a producer as well as a consumer. This is because it's an invariant generic class defined as `ArrayList<T>` ,not as `ArrayList<out T>`(producer) or `ArrayList<in T>`(consumer). This means the class can have functions that accept `T` as a function parameter (consume) or return `T` (produce).

But what if you want to use this already existing class safely just as a consumer(`in T`) or just as a producer(`out T`)? Without worrying about the accidental use of the other unwanted functionality?

In that case, we project the types by using variance modifiers `in` and `out`
at the use-site. *Use-site* simply means wherever we use the `ArrayList<T>` class.

---

### `out` produces `T` and the function accepts subtypes

When you are using the `ArrayList` as a producer(`out`), the function can accept the subtypes of `ArrayList<Orange>`, that is, `ArrayList<MandarinOrange>`, `ArrayList<BloodOrange>`, since `MandarinOrange` and `BloodOrange` are subtypes of `Orange`. Because the subtyping is preserved:

```
fun useAsProducer(producer: ArrayList<out Orange>) {

    // Producer produces Orange and its subtypes
    val orange = producer.get(1)            // OK

    // Can use functions and properties of Orange
    orange.getVitaminC()                    // OK

    // Consumer functions not allowed
    producer.add(BloodOrange())             // Error
}
```

The `producer` produces `Orange` and its subtypes. Here `producer.get(1)` can return `MandarinOrange`, `BloodOrange` etc. but we don't care as long as we get an `Orange`. Because we are only interested in using the properties and functions of `Orange` at use-site.

Compiler doesn't allow calling the `add()` function (consumer) because we don't know which type of `Orange` it contains. You don't want to accidentally add `BloodOrange`, if this is an `ArrayList<MandarinOrange>`.

---

### `in` consumes `T` and the function accepts supertypes

When you are using `ArrayList` as a consumer(`in`), the function can accept the supertypes of `ArrayList<Orange>`, that is, `ArrayList<Fruit>` because now the subtyping is reversed. This means `ArrayList<Fruit>` is a subtype of `ArrayList<Orange>` when `Orange` is a subtype of `Fruit`:

```
fun useAsConsumer(consumer: ArrayList<in Orange>) {

    // Produces Any?, no guarantee of Orange because this could
    // be an ArrayList<Fruit> with apples in it
    val anyNullable = consumer.get(1)       // Not useful

    // Not safe to call functions of Orange on the produced items.
    anyNullable.getVitaminC()               // Error

    // Consumer consumes Orange and its subtypes
    consumer.add(MandarinOrange())          // OK
}
```

The `consumer` consumes `Orange` and its subtypes. It doesn't matter whether it's a `MandarinOrange` or a `BloodOrange` as long as it's an `Orange`. Because the `consumer` is only interested in the properties and functions of `Orange` at its declaration-site.

The compiler does allow the call to `get()` function (producer) but it produces `Any?` which is not useful for us. The compiler flags an error when you use that `Any?` as an `Orange` at use-site.

---

### Invariant produces and consumes `T`, the function doesn't accept subtypes or supertypes

When you are using `ArrayList` as a producer and consumer (without `in` or `out`), the function can accept only the exact type `ArrayList<Orange>`, no other subtypes like `ArrayList<MandarinOrange>` or supertypes like `ArrayList<Fruit>`. Because the subtyping is not allowed for invariants:

```
fun useAsProducerConsumer(producerConsumer: ArrayList<Orange>) {
    // Produces Orange and its subtypes
    val orange = producerConsumer.get(1)    // OK

    // Orange is guaranteed
    orange.getVitaminC()                    // OK

    // Consumes Orange and its subtypes
    producerConsumer.add(Orange())          // OK
}
```

The invariant produces and consumes `Orange` and its subtypes.

---

That's it! Type projection is all about telling the compiler how you are using that class in that particular function, so it can help you by flagging an error if you call unintended functions accidentally. Hope that helps.

Comment: the initial table already explains a lot :) Ty

Answer (score 4):

For **in** generic, we could assign a class of *super-type* to class of *sub-type*.
But for **out** generic, we could assign a class of *sub-type* to class of *super-type*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please describe your answer more so easily understand by another person

Answer (score 1):

It's about covariant and contravariance. When you say that your function accepts `List<out T>`, it means that it can accept `List<T>` or any List typed by class that inherited from `T`. In the other hand, function with `List<in T>` can accept a `List<T>` and any List typed by `T` superclass.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is incorrect. The members of that list must all implement the full interface of the generic type. One of that types super types is not going to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I think I incorrectly expressed my thought. I have corrected the answer.